# Django - Store user location data with GeoDjango

Tags: django, geodjango

I want to use GeoDjango to get retrieve from the user location point information like city, country, etc.
In order to use GeoDjango I have to install `PostGIS` which adds geographic object support to PostgreSQL.

Questions:

1. Do I have to install `PostGIS` on the default database or is a best practice to store location data in different database?
2. Can I mix `django.db.models` and `django.contrib.gis.db.models` to make clear difference between GeoDjango fields and the default ones?

Example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geo_models

class Profile(models.Model):
    """
    This model extends the `User` model as an One-To-One link.
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    location = geo_models.PointField()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The same database is fine (and makes things that much easier.)
2. You can mix them. Same with the postgres contrib fields; you just use them where you need to.

And I know you didn't ask this, but if possible, it'll simplify things to [use a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) instead of an one-to-one extension model like you've illustrated.